# Optimize intersection between list and really large dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have to process a column of a data frame which has roughly a size of 15k to 20K. I have to process the column 'name' in it for which i have called df.apply

```
df['bew_col']=df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row['persons_name']), axis=1)

def valuation_formula(name_str):

    flag='UNMAPPED'
    sr=name_str.split(' ')
    f=list(set(sr).intersection(set(name_dict.keys())))
    # print (f)
    if len(f)>0:
        flag=name_dict[str(f[0])]
        # print flag

    return flag
```

my name_dict is a dictionary with 5 million keys. how can i optimise my code to do an efficient intersection of a list of strings (which would be small hence not a case of worry) with keys in this huge dictionary to return the corresponding value for the key matched?

can i use any other data structure?

now the script takes 20 min to run. with df size of 10k and name_dict size of 3 million.

Answer (score 0):

try `.str` and `map`:

```
names_series = df['persons_name']
name_mapping = None

while True:
    name_series = name_series.str.partition()
    mapping = name_series[0].map(name_dict)
    if name_mapping is None:
        name_mapping = mapping
    else:
        name_mapping[name_mapping.isnull() & (~mapping.isnull())]=mapping
    name_series = name_series[2]
    if name_series.str.len().sum()==0:
        break

name_series[name_series.isnull()] = 'UNMAPPED'
df['bew_col'] = name_series
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i cannot execute the statement name_series = df['persons_name'].str.partition(' ')[0] directly as then only the first name of the string would be considerd (e.g. Oshin Sanjay Patwa) here it will map only for Oshin and not 'Sanjay' 'Patwa' i want to check presense of all the words in the string in name_dict.keys() , so could i use the map function in my valuation_formula function as:  f=list(set(sr).map(name_dict.keys()). Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: @Oshin Patwa ,are  the words of name always less than 3?

Comment: @lan hey no not always it varies but yeah i can find out the string with maximum number of words in that case from the 'name' column of the data frame would that be use full then?